# Related to the CDF of product of two independent exponential random variables (Basic Query)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If we have two i.i.d. exponential random variables $X$ and $Y$ each with mean $1$. Then is it right to write $$P(XY>c)=e^{-c}$$ I will be very surprised if it is right but I read in a very reputable journal (I have added the relevant images from the paper in my post below and highlighted them).
enter image description here

[image: Page 6 of the paper]

[image: Page 7 of the paper]

Comment: Which journal? $ $

Comment: @Did Its IEEE Transactions on Vehicular Technology. The link of paper is as http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7551186/ (if you can not open it then I can provide the pdf of the paper). In this paper Eq 24 and discussion below it says that product of two iid exponential random variables is also an exponential random variable. Similar argument is used in a later equation in that same paper. Therefore, I highly doubt that its a pen mistake. Is it something very crucial that I am missing here? Any comments on this because I am quite confused over this as the journal is top 10% in our field.

Comment: Paywall indeed.

Comment: @Did I have added the relevant pages in my original post (I was unable to upload the whole pdf file). The relevant discussion is highlighted for convenience. It is clearly mentioned that the two random variables are i.i.d. exponential random variables and their product yield another exponential random variable (since the CDF used is of an exponential random variable in Eq 23). Same logic is applied in the first  equation of page 7 also therefore we can say that its not a pen mistake. I can send you the whole file through some other source(like email etc) because of no file upload option in SE

Comment: Indeed the key passage is the paragraph that you highlighted, just after equation (24). Already its formulation is odd since it reads "(...) we consider that the product of two independent exponential random variables [that is, your $XY$] yield(s) another random variable and hence (a) follows from the distribution of exponential random variable (...)". Why "we consider" and not "it is a fact that"? It is true that "the product of two (...) random variables (...) yield(s) another random variable"... but with which distribution? It may well happen that the authors are well aware of the fact ...

Comment: ... that $XY$ is not exponential but that they decided to continue their computations as if it were, for tractability. In defense of this choice, note that the true PDF $f_Z$ is decreasing, like an exponential PDF, and that its mean is indeed $1$. Against it, one should mention that $f_Z$ is NOT exponential, that $f_Z(0)$ is infinite (instead of finite), and that $f_Z(z)$ is of order $e^{-2\sqrt{z}}$ when $z\to\infty$, not $e^{-z}$. (Oh, and also that misleading the reader through ambiguous formulations at the key moment is not commendable, if you ask me.)

Comment: @Did thanks for clarifying things.